# Применение blur при программном добавлении многоуровневой иерархии View

Tags: android, view, blur

В рамках проекта есть необходимость построить одно View программно на основе xml, css и архива с ассетами. В xml для некоторых составляющих разметки этого view есть характеристика blurred у которой boolean значение. Потратил много часов пытаясь применять различные способы для размытия, найденые на просторах великого и могучего - не работало ничего. То есть код компилировался без ошибок, но никаких внешних изменений я не видел. Тогда я решил что прежде чем встраивать что-то для меня новое в сложную структуру надо для начала пойти от простого. Взял за основу [чудесную статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/215077/) и в разметку добавил ImageView. Сделал на основе статьи два метода:

```
public static void applyBlur(final View parent, final View blurring) {
    parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            parent.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bmp = parent.getDrawingCache();
            blur(bmp, blurring);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

И

```
private static void blur(Bitmap bkg, View view) {

    float radius = 10;

    Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);
    canvas.translate(-view.getLeft(), -view.getTop());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bkg, 0, 0, null);
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(view.getContext());
    Allocation overlayAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs, overlay);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
            rs, overlayAlloc.getElement());
    blur.setInput(overlayAlloc);
    blur.setRadius(radius);
    blur.forEach(overlayAlloc);
    overlayAlloc.copyTo(overlay);
    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(view.getContext().getResources(), overlay));
    rs.destroy();
}
```

И о чудо. Оно сработало. ImageView я поначалу сделал маленький и разместил его там, где он точно пересекался бы с каким нибудь View из моей разметки. Решил расширить его (ImageView), так как разметку, которую я создавал из css и xml я тестировал на той же активити попросту добавляя программно

```
    Iterator<Template> templateIterator = Template.templates().iterator();
    Template template = templateIterator.next();
    View view = template.view(this);
    if (view != null) {
        container.addView(view);
    }
```

После чего я увидел, что ImageView с блюр эффектом размывает все, кроме добавленного программно view. Я убедился что этот ImafeView находится "над" всеми остальными View в разметке, пересобрал и увидел, что  созданное программно View попало в "скриншот", который мы размываем и вставляем в ImageView только частично. Попробовал заблюрить часть разметки созданного программно View (сделал для этого container из кода выше public static и указал его в качестве parent) и получил в разметке созданного программно view "скриншот" того, что находится в разметке активити под ним, но не того, что находится в разметке созданного программно View

На скриншотах ниже показаны первый и второй случай (первый - картинка растянута почти на всю разметку, второй )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идеи, почему так может происходить и как нужно поступать, чтобы размыть View создаваемые программно?

UPDATE

Вопрос следует немного изменить. Для начала немного о иерархии созданного программно View. Я не буду сильно углубляться, сейчас достаточно этого

```
RelativeLayout -  container
|--- ImageView -  image for blurring
|--- RelativeLayout - blurrer
```

Необходимо добиться того, чтобы blurrer размывал все, что находится под ним - в данном случае это ImageView. Разметка в итоге будет глубже и Внутренний RelativeLayout тоже может содержать Layout который будет блюррить все, что под ним.

Сейчас я попробовал убрать из иерархии ImageView и получил результат - то есть я взял картинку, поставил ее в качестве backgroundDrawable для container и вызвал свои методы где в качестве parent выступал container а в качестве blurring - blurrer. В итоге я получил размытие. Но сложность в том, что в иерархии разметки на основании которой я строю свой View картинка идет на одном уровне с blurrer'ом и надо чтобы он оказался "выше" нее и размыл её. Как можно этого добиться?

UPDATE 2

Создается впечатление, что когда я создаю разметку в xml - родительский контейнер "знает" о View, которые в нем находятся, а когда программно - нет. Каким нибудь образом можно "дать понять" созданному программно корневому контейнеру, что в нем есть иерархия view и сделать что то вроде bind перед применением blur? По идее это должно сработать

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему. Причиной был Universal Image Loader который загружал картинку в ImageView асинхронно, что приводило к тому, что размытие созданного View происходило ДО того, как картинка была показана. И так, как на родительском layout пока нет других View, внешне эффекта не было - размытие монотонного цвета и выглядит монотонно. Я стал загружать картинку в UI Thread и добился того, что она оказывалась в плейсхолдере ДО того, как происходит размытие. В таком случае "скриншот" создается корректно и эффект на лицо. Всем спасибо за внимание